# Android : unable to start activity

Tags: java, android

I have an activity that has a button which supposed to open another class (activity 
without layout), when I hit this button the app gets stopped.

I tried so many solutions that were provided, but it didn't work out due to different lines of code

Here's my code:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.baharat2; 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Button signin_btn ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    signin_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    signin_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Basic.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }
}
```

Basic.java

```
package com.example.baharat2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.parse.ParseAnonymousUtils;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

public class Basic extends Activity{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Determine whether the current user is an anonymous user
    if (ParseAnonymousUtils.isLinked(ParseUser.getCurrentUser())) {
        // If user is anonymous, send the user to LoginSignupActivity.class
        Intent intent = new Intent(Basic.this,LoginSignupActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        // If current user is NOT anonymous user
        // Get current user data from Parse.com
        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            // Send logged in users to Welcome.class
            Intent intent = new Intent(Basic.this, Welcome.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            // Send user to LoginSignupActivity.class
            Intent intent =Intent(Basic.this,LoginSignupActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
      }

   }
}
```

Any ideas for what causing this error ?

Comment: You should post your logcat. But most likely, `Basic.java` is not declared in your `manifest.xml`. Actually there could be many issues now that I look closer. Post your logcat.

Comment: Ps. All activities has been added to the manifest

Comment: Post your code for second activity

Comment: @mike20132013 I'm not sure more code is needed right now. Logcat first. There is plenty of code here already

Comment: @user3368149, logically speaking, what is the point of the `Basic` activity? Why not just do all of that in your main activity? All you seem to be doing is deciding what activity to launch.

Comment: The analysis of this problem would be _much_ easier by looking at logcat output

Comment: @user1153551 answered it, Thanks everyone

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put your Basic.java content into MainActivity. No need to create for this 2nd activity its not any UI interface.  So activity 2nd not `setContentView` so its main problem so i thing do something like this,

MainActivty.java

```
package com.example.baharat2; 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.parse.ParseAnonymousUtils;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Button signin_btn ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    signin_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    signin_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
            // Determine whether the current user is an anonymous user
            if (ParseAnonymousUtils.isLinked(ParseUser.getCurrentUser())) {
                // If user is anonymous, send the user to LoginSignupActivity.class
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginSignupActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
            // If current user is NOT anonymous user
            // Get current user data from Parse.com
            ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            if (currentUser != null) {
                // Send logged in users to Welcome.class
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Welcome.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                // Send user to LoginSignupActivity.class
                Intent intent =Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginSignupActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
        }
      }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }
}
```

Comment: I agree that `Basic.java` appears to be useless as an `Activity` but this shouldn't be causing the problem. It doesn't have to call `setContentView()`

Comment: yes, i think you right @codeMagic. thanks for remind me. may be this is not UI activity so missing to register activity type in manifirst.xml

Comment: No, OP already said they are all in the manifest. Anyway, too many possibilities so not worth trying to solve without logcat

Comment: @user1153551 Thank you it works, actually now I have another error which is : the jar of this class belongs to container android private libraries > Any good solution ?